# Get page contributors on github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I was wondering if there is a way to get the contibutors to a page on github pages using the [`github-metadata`](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/) gem. I know that you can use `site.github.contributors` to get all the contributors to the site, but I was wondering specifically about getting the contributors to that page.

For example, on [Primer](https://primer.style)'s documentation, they have the contributors to the current page at the bottom of that page:

[image: photo of primer documentation]
Source: [Primer UI Patterns: Empty states](https://primer.style/design/ui-patterns/empty-states)

Thank you so much!